# Reload function when sourcing init.lua

Tags: neovim, lua

In "~/.config/nvim/lua/foo.lua" I have the following

```
local M = {}

function M.test()
  vim.notify("hello")
end
return M
```

And then in my `init.lua` I have

```
local test = require('foo').test
vim.keymap.set('n', "gh", test)
```

If I start up nvim, everything works as expected. However, if I change the string that `test` notifies and then `source` my `init.lua`, it still messages "hello". Is there a way to "re-source" my other lua modules when I `source` my `init.lua`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force `require` 'foo' again, you can set `package.loaded['foo'] = nil`.

Therefore, if you do this in your `init.lua`, it reloads 'foo' every time automatically.

```lua
package.loaded['foo'] = nil
local test = require('foo').test
vim.keymap.set('n', "gh", test)
```

It is likely that you would `require` multiple packages in your config.
A helper function would be useful.

```lua
local function import(module)
    package.loaded[module] = nil
    return require(module)
end

local test = import('foo').test
vim.keymap.set('n', "gh", test)
```

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks!